# Security Prompt Paypal

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pycharm, selenium-chromedriver

I've been messing around with Python and Pycharm a bit and I started programming a Paypal-auto-account script. Now, I've had some problems, especially with the Security Prompt site of Paypal which, obviously, prevents the script to go on. (To be exact: It "waits" for around 20 seconds and then aborts the script). 
I am using the newest Pycharm/Python drivers with chromedriver (version 79)
I've heard about some options about the implicity_wait code but I just can't get it to work...

I want selenium to wait until I did the ReCaptcha thing that appears while wanting to confirm my password.

Much love for everyone who's (at least trying) to help. Thank you

Here's the Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\ASUS\Downloads\chromedriver.exe")

browser.get("https://www.paypal.com/welcome/signup?country.x=GB")
browser.implicitly_wait(30)

browser.find_element_by_id("acceptAllButton")
cookies = browser.find_element_by_id("acceptAllButton")
cookies.click()


browser.find_element_by_id("paypalAccountData_countryselector")
GB = browser.find_element_by_id("paypalAccountData_countryselector")
GB.click()

browser.find_element_by_id("paypalAccountData_firstName")
Name1 = browser.find_element_by_id("paypalAccountData_firstName")
Name1.click()
Name1.send_keys("James")

browser.find_element_by_id("paypalAccountData_lastName")
Name2 = browser.find_element_by_id("paypalAccountData_lastName")
Name2.click()
Name2.send_keys("Charles")

browser.find_element_by_id("paypalAccountData_email")
email = browser.find_element_by_id("paypalAccountData_email")
email.click()
email.send_keys("TheEmail@gmail.com")


browser.find_element_by_id("paypalAccountData_password")
Password = browser.find_element_by_id("paypalAccountData_password")
Password.click()
Password.send_keys("TheEmail12!")

browser.find_element_by_id("paypalAccountData_addressSuggest")
Adress = browser.find_element_by_id("paypalAccountData_addressSuggest")
Adress.click()
Adress.send_keys("SW1A 1BD")

browser.find_element_by_id("paypalAccountData_address2")
Adress2 = browser.find_element_by_id("paypalAccountData_address2")
Adress2.click()
Adress2.send_keys("Warwick House")

browser.find_element_by_id("paypalAccountData_address1")
ADL1 = browser.find_element_by_id("paypalAccountData_address1")
ADL1.click()
ADL1.send_keys("St. James's Palace")

browser.find_element_by_id("paypalAccountData_city")
City = browser.find_element_by_id("paypalAccountData_city")
City.click()
City.send_keys("London")

browser.find_element_by_id("paypalAccountData_phoneType")
Number = browser.find_element_by_id("paypalAccountData_phoneType")
Number.click()

browser.find_element_by_id("paypalAccountData_phone")
Number1 = browser.find_element_by_id("paypalAccountData_phone")
Number1.click()
Number1.send_keys("87536718921")

browser.find_element_by_id("paypalAccountData_dob")
DateOfBirth = browser.find_element_by_id("paypalAccountData_dob")
DateOfBirth.click()
DateOfBirth.send_keys("02041996")

browser.find_element_by_id("paypalAccountData_oneTouchCheckbox")
Checkout = browser.find_element_by_id("paypalAccountData_oneTouchCheckbox")
Checkout.click()

browser.find_element_by_id("paypalAccountData_tcpa")
Checkout2 = browser.find_element_by_id("paypalAccountData_tcpa")
Checkout2.click()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I see you're a new contributor, so I advise you to check out [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). At the moment, its not quite clear what you question is. Are your asking how to bypass PayPal's ReCaptcha and/or security prompts? Or are you looking for how to make your script wait until the page reaches a certain state?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the time module. Just write:

```
import time
time.sleep(x)
```

Comment: Yeeeah thanks but the problem is I'd waste lots of time waiting for the code to go on if I solve the ReCaptcha

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using implicit wait for a certain time, could you try explicitly waiting for an element to become available, or some other condition which changes after you do the captcha?

An example of waiting for an element is provided in the selenium documentation here: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://somedomain/url_that_delays_loading")
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "myDynamicElement"))
    )
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: Thanks man !  Just had to change some things and specificate here and there, but the code itself helped me a lot.

Comment: @Razorbackfire If this solved your problem, please feel free to mark it as the answer. It's helpful for me and everyone else down the road to know what did the trick for you.